# read data from arduino and react when data is larger than a zero

Tags: c#, serial-port

in c# 
i'm trying to read data from arduino so when the data is not "0" i will get a reaction.

The signal from arduino is ok and displays on the label but i cannot use the "<" condition.

```
        private void ArduinoTMR_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string ard1 = Arduino.ReadLine();

        label2.Text = ard1;
        if (ard1 > "0")
        {
            label2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
            label2.BackColor = Color.Blue;    

    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: why do you even think that you can compare a `string` with the `>` operator?? you can't. You would first have to convert it to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because you're comparing two strings and not numbers. Mathematical operators like `>` can't be applied to strings.

This is what you're looking for:

```
private void ArduinoTMR_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ard1 = Arduino.ReadLine();

    label2.Text = ard1;

    if(!int.TryParse(ard1, out var state)) return; // try to convert text to a number

    label2.BackColor = state > 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Blue; // now compare the parsed number to the number 0
}
```

If what you get from your Arduino is only 1 or 0, you could think about parsing it to a byte as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `>` or `<` operators with the strings, you have to do this before:

```
int ard1converted=Convert.ToInt32(ard1);
```

and then

```
if (ard1converted> 0)
//do something
```